# Live server error but not on MAMP

Tags: php, session, header, mamp, pyrocms

I have just done a fresh install of the latest stable PyroCMS version on my web server. I now can hardly use the site due to PHP errors pertaining to session data. "Cannot modify header data."

Why would the CMS run without error on MAMP but not on the live server?

Comment: Thanks, I've seen the reply below and will have a look at playing with error reporting. Incidentally, I have been able to get access to another server to test this on and it has no problems, any ideas why this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. I eventually found the problem which was to do with sessions. I had `session.autostart=on` on the live server. Turning this off fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Looks like PyroCMS is having trouble with php 5.4 which is what MAMP is using by default. Try switching your php version to 5.3.

[Thread with same issue](https://www.pyrocms.com/forums/topics/view/18863)

Answer (score 0):

Both the server must be having different configurations with regards to displaying of errors.

Either place `error_report('E_ALL');` at the initial page (most probably `index.php`) or find out how you can disable displaying errors in your CMS (there must be some configurations).

Or trying putting `off` the `display_errors` directive in your `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

You should have PHP set up so that you spot errors on your local machine before they make it to production. It seems like you currently have this the wrong way around!

To fix it, your dev install of MAMP should have error_reporting set to E_ALL in php.ini and display_errors set to 'on'. Your production webserver should have display_errors set to 'off' at the very least (check that they are sent to the log files instead - you don't want to lose them) and you may also wish to reduce error_reporting to E_ERROR.

Setting it to E_ERROR will keep the logs on the production server clean so that you can spot big problems when they happen. You may especially want to do this if you are using a library or CMS that produces PHP notices or warnings, which you can't do anything about. Alternatively, you may wish to keep everything going to the logs with E_ALL and systematically sort out all the stuff that shows up, however, you will need to be using code that you can modify without making it awkward to upgrade. This can be very useful because sometimes the environment on the production server differs from your local one and things can genuinely break for reasons you don't expect.

Incidentally, the 'cannot modify header data' error suggests that this is not a stable version of PyroCMS, whatever it says on the tin!

Comment: PyroCMS does actually have control over error levels built in. There's an Apache environment variable called 'PYRO_ENV' which can be DEVELOPMENT, STAGING or PRODUCTION and is set to DEVELOPMENT in default installs - there's a line in the [standard .htaccess file](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/blob/2.1/develop/.htaccess) you can comment in which sets it to production. [Display_errors](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) is enabled/disabled via the 'Error Reporting' section of [index.php](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/blob/2.1/develop/index.php)